# Cannot target the parent using children or childnodes

Tags: javascript

I am not able to target the parent or children using parentElement or children or childNotes in console I got an error of cannot read the properties of null. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Where's your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.